# Suppose that $|f(z)| \leq e^{-1/|z|}$ for all $z\neq 0$. Prove that $f=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose f is entire function such that $$|f(z)| \leq e^{-1/|z|}$$ for all $z\neq 0$. Show that $f=0$.

Hint: Consider the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$ and recursively show that all coefficients must vanish.

Even with the hint, I'm not sure what to do. I'm not sure how I can find a Taylor series based only on the information that I am given. I am reminded of Liouville's Theorem though.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint:  $\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k z^k\right|\le e^{-1/n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded by $1$ for all $z\ne 0$ and is entire, Liouville's Theorem guarantees$|f(z)|$ is constant, say $f(z)=C$.  Then, $|f(z)|=C\le e^{-1/n}$ for all $n$ implies that $C=0$.

Comment: You're welcome Joe.  My pleasure. - Mark